# C-O bond strength in metal carbonyls

Tags: coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds, carbonyl-complexes

The metal carbonyls (and similar organometallic compounds) involve a combination of a $\sigma$-bond, a $\pi$-bond and backbonding. The bond strengths under consideration are the metal-carbon bond and the carbon oxygen bond. Here is the original question:

> Predict the order of $\ce{C−O}$ bond strength in the following:
>   **I**) $\ce{[Mn(CO)6]+}$
>   **II**) $\ce{[Cr(CO)6]}$
>   **III**) $\ce{[V(CO)6]-}$

All of these are isoelectronic, and hence whatever the difference of bond strengths, must arise from the difference in the resultant nuclear force of attraction. Since $\ce{Mn+}$ has the highest charge density, I would assume that the $\ce{M−C}$ bond strength of the manganese compound is the strongest (vanadium being the weakest) and therefore, the $\ce{C-O}$ bond strength must follow the opposite order, as the strengthening of the metal carbonyl bond should weaken the carbon oxygen bond.

But the answer given is $\mathrm{III<II<I}$, exactly the opposite of my prediction. Why is it so? A relevant factor which I didn't consider is the back bonding, but I am unsure of how to integrate that into my prediction. Also, how would we make a prediction if the given compounds were not isoelectronic?

Comment: You did learn about backbonding, right? With simple CO complexes like these, the M to C backbonding is likely to be more significant than the ordinary sigma bond from C to M. And backbonding increases in the order Mn+ < Cr < V-.